# Why aren't MVC3 webgrid paging and sorting working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I'm using MVC3 webgrid to display, sort and paginate data. The display is fine, but when I click on a new page or request a sort, nothing is happening.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
      @if (Model.AdsList != null)
    {

    WebGrid adGrid = new WebGrid(Model.AdsList, rowsPerPage: 10, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "adsGrid");
    <div>
  @adGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
            @adGrid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                headerStyle: "header",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                htmlAttributes: new { id = "adsGrid", width = "100%" },
                columns: adGrid.Columns(
                                        //columns
        ));
    </div>
}
```

The data is loading correctly, but none of the links generated are working. Is there anything I need to do in `controller` for paging and sorting?

**EDIT** : I am getting this page as a result of post operation from another page .There is not GET action with same name in the controller.

code is shown below   in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
    {
            //some operation
           return view(model);
    }
```

I also like to know how paging is working . Is the webgrid query against data base every time when i click next page or sort links?

Comment: Check out this article on sorting in webgrid: http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/02/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid-part-2.aspx

Comment: put a debugger to your controller and click on the pagination or click the row headers. Does debugger fire when you click headers?

Answer (score 4):

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 6,canPage: true, canSort: true, ); 

@grid.GetHtml(headerStyle: "gridtableheader", footerStyle: "paging",                  
columns:
 grid.Columns(
//Columns
),
mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
```

// different modes of paging

```
mode: WebGridPagerModes.FirstLast
mode: WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious
mode: WebGridPagerModes.Numeric
```

Hope This will solve your problem